# Show textbox text highlight while textbox is out of focus

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus

I have a textbox with some text in it. How do I prevent the textbox from hiding the selected text highlight when the textbox loses focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set

```
textBox1.IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled = true;
```

(Apparently this is new in  Fx 4.5)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, problem is that I am developing for .Net Framework 4.

Comment: Well, if it's directly supported by a new property then there probably isn't an easy way to do it in earlier versions.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. If there's no standard way of doing it in earlier versions, that makes your answer valid. Thank you.

Comment: IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled doesn't seem to work in .net 4.5.2 or 4.6.1

Comment: I found it to work in 4.6.1, but it's named poorly - all it does is keep whatever selection was there when the control _lost_ focus.. any changes occurring while it doesn't have focus are not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend from the TextBox class, and play around with the SelectionChanged event.

Most of the time, changing default behaviour of controls is a bad idea. The user could experience it as unexpected behaviour, which is bad. In your case, if you manage to create such textbox, the user could select text in multiple textboxes at te same time, since the selection doesn't hide.

Tell me, what is the reason why you want the selected text to remain highlighted? 'Cause maybe there is another way.

**EDIT**: Apparantly such feature is supported in .NET 4.5: `IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using a temporary image overlay isn't an option. Having text selected in multiple textboxes isn't a problem because I only use one text box in the project context. The reason I want to keep text highlighted is because I want the user to know what part of the text is selected when the textbox loses focus.

+1 though for your edit as it is what Henk also suggested as a solution (in Net 4.5).

Comment: I wonder what would happen if the user tries to copy (CTRL+C) the selected text, while the focus is somewhere else. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the completed solution with XAML. The solution keywords are:

- IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled
- InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey

With `IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled` you can enable the feature
end with `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush` you can override the default brush which is 'Transparent'

```
<Style x:Key="TextBox.AlwaysShowSelection" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush 
            x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" 
            Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

And yes you can also override the InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush in global scope, but I wanted to show it only for a specific textbox style.

*Because we have meanwhile 2022. I use .NET 6.0 but this should work also in older frameworks (but not too old like .NET 4.0 ;-)*

Comment: Setting that brush key doesn't appear to have any effect.  The bool property does though not for showing selection changes after the focus was lost.

Answer (score -1):

You could Use the code Below on both the On Focus and Leaving Focus event handlers :-

```
textbox.SelectionStart = 0;
textbox.SelectionLength = textbox.Text.Length;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the selection highlight is still hidden when focus is lost.

Comment: This only changes the Selection in the box, no effect on visibility.